# HttpClientFactory Create method not working in .Net Framework 4.8 HttpClient is working

Tags: .net, web-services, webservice-client, .net-4.8

I have the web service developed in .Net framework 4.8 and the httpRuntime targetFramework points to 4.0. When I change the targetFramework  to 4.8 the Http calls either timing out or returning 403 Forbidden error. But it works with targetFramework 4.0. Also If i use HttpClient object it works.

Don't know what is the major difference between creating HttpClient object vs HttpClientFactory.Create()
If anyone solved this issue or know the solution please share. Thanks in Advance.

**Configuration (Web.Config) :** Not working

```
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
```

The Code am using to call the API (looks similar except the business logic.)

```
public async Task<string> TestMethodAsync()
{    
    HttpClientWrapper clientWrapper = new HttpClientWrapper();
    HttpResponseMessage response = clientWrapper.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result;
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
}

public class HttpClientWrapper
{
    private readonly CustomDelegatingHandler _delegatingHandler = new CustomDelegatingHandler();
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(_delegatingHandler))
        {
            return await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        }
    }   
    public class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {         
                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those `.Result` calls actually in your code? If so, [that's your problem right there](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Hi Stephen Cleary, Thanks for the reply. I just edited my question slightly and I think the issue is in the HttpClient object created by HttpClientFactory. Because without in overriding anything in the delegatinghandler it is not working but it works with direct HttpClient object.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, using ConfigureAwait(false) in all places resolved the issue. Both of your below article helped understanding the root cause and thanks for sharing very detail.                 https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html,                                                                                              
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is fine, but the best solution is to go [async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#async-all-the-way):

```
public async Task<string> TestMethodAsync()
{    
  HttpClientWrapper clientWrapper = new HttpClientWrapper();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await clientWrapper.GetAsync("https://www.google.com");
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added the ConfigureAwait(false) wherever awiat is used and that resolved the issue. Below is the updated code

```
public async Task<string> TestMethodAsync()
{    
    HttpClientWrapper clientWrapper = new HttpClientWrapper();
    HttpResponseMessage response = clientWrapper.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result;
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
}
public class HttpClientWrapper
{
    private readonly CustomDelegatingHandler _delegatingHandler = new CustomDelegatingHandler();
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(_delegatingHandler))
        {
            return await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }   
    public class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {         
            
    }
}
```

Found the solution from the below blogs, and here it is explained in very detail
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html